# Is there a column in Windows Explorer for "Original Air Date?"

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-media-center, metadata

I want to sort the Windows Media Center Recorded TV folder wtv files by original air date in Windows Explorer.  There are about 300 different columns to choose from, but none that I can tell correspond to the original air date metadata.  Is this information available in an Explorer column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Windows "date" field is already set to the original broadcast date, or the date and time of recording if this metadata wasn't published in the guide.

The name of the dedicated metadata field is "broadcast date".  Just right click on the header row in Windows Explorer, select "More," then scroll down to "Broadcast Date" and select it.  Then you can click on the "Broadcast Date" column to sort by it.

Other useful fields that are populated are "Station Name", "Episode Name", "Channel number", "Recording time", "Length", and "Program Description".